# MVC Razor: Preview HTML email template (master was not found)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an email template management page written in MVC Razor, and I'm attempting to render the HTML in a blank tab in order to preview the templates.  I'm rendering the HTML as follows, passing the HTML in as a model:

```
@model string

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Preview Email Template";
    Layout = "";
}

@Html.Raw(Model)
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
The view '<!DOCTYPE html>....</html>' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/EmailTemplate/<!DOCTYPE html>...
```

Any ideas on how to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try changing Layout to null instead of empty string:

```
@model string

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Preview Email Template";
    Layout = null;
}

@Html.Raw(Model)
```

For previewing a page in a blank tab or window, you may add `target="_blank"` attribute on your form or action link:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Controller", "Action", FormMethod.Post, new { target="_blank" })) { ... }

@Html.ActionLink("Text", "Action", new { controller = "Controller" }, new { target="_blank" })
```

Also, make sure you're returning proper view name and model contains HTML tags inside controller code.

```
public ActionResult Preview()
{
    String model = "<!DOCTYPE html>....</html>";
    // some code here
    return View("viewname", model); // viewname is your cshtml file name
}
```

I assumed you're trying to return raw HTML string as view name, thus "master was not found" error thrown by view engine.

Comment: You were onto something with the view name, I tried to name the view but still no luck, so I solved it by going back to using a class-based view model instead of a string, with null layout.